# How can I let the iOS Speech framework distinguish actual user's voice and record voice (e.g. mp3)?

Tags: ios, swift, speech-to-text

My app is a Speech-to-Text app that enables to playback of the mp3 that is another user's dictated voice at the same time via iPhone speaker. It's like a pseudo phone call

I'm facing the issue that while playing an mp3, the iOS Speech framework detects it as a user's speech that is not expected. I want the framework to only detect the actual user's voice who is speaking in front of the iPhone.

I'm not sure if it's possible in the first place. However, I guess it somehow is since when I use the iOS Notes app and use the dictation feature on the keyboard, it doesn't detect the recorded voice (even though I play it very loudly!). So how can I realize the same?

My piece of code as a reference.

```swift
private var speechRecognizer: SFSpeechRecognizer?
private var recognitionRequest: SFSpeechAudioBufferRecognitionRequest?
private var audioEngine: AVAudioEngine?

func start() {
    self.speechRecognizer = SFSpeechRecognizer(locale: Locale(identifier: "ja-JP"))
    self.recognitionRequest = .init()
    self.audioEngine = .init()

    let inputNode = self.audioEngine?.inputNode
    let recordingFormat = inputNode?.outputFormat(forBus: 0)
    inputNode?.installTap(onBus: 0, bufferSize: 1024, format: recordingFormat) { buffer, _ in
        self.recognitionRequest?.append(buffer)
    }

    self.audioEngine?.prepare()
    try? self.audioEngine?.start()
}
```

Comment: I think you should stop sound in others apps first before starting your voice detection. And after you done your detection, open back the sound currently playing in others app.

Comment: @bewithyou MP3 is being played by my app and I don't want to stop it even while doing speech recognition.

Comment: So it seems hard. I think it will cause wrong detection like you said above.

Comment: I see. I'm wondering how the iOS Notes app realize it though 

Comment: I tested the note app by apple. I see that it stops sound when start speech to text. Or you can build your own framework to detect with sound